# How to join 2 columns of word embeddings in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have extracted word embeddings of 2 different texts (title and description) and want to train an `XGBoost` model on both embeddings. The embeddings are `200` in dimension each as can be seen below:

[image]

Now I was able to train the model on 1 embedding data and it worked perfectly like this:

```
x=df['FastText']  #training features
y=df['Category'] # target variable

#Defining Model
model = XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softprob')

#Evaluation metrics
score=['accuracy','precision_macro','recall_macro','f1_macro']

#Model training with 5 Fold Cross Validation
scores = cross_validate(model,  np.vstack(x), y, cv=5, scoring=score)
```

Now I want to use both the features for training but it gives me an error if I pass 2 columns of df like this:

```
x=df[['FastText_Title','FastText']]
```

One solution I tried is adding both the embeddings like x1+x2 but it decreases accuracy significantly. How do I use both features in `cross_validate` function?

Answer (score 0):

In the past for multiple inputs, I've done this:

```
features = ['FastText_Title', 'FastText']
x = df[features]
y = df['Category']
```

It is creating an array containing both datasets.
I usually need to scale the data as well using MinMaxScaler once the new array has been made.

Comment: It gives this error:

ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool.
                Did not expect the data types in fields FastText_Title, FastText

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, maybe because data in these df columns are lists on their own, it doesn't like that

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you are getting, it seems that there is something wrong with types. Try this, it will convert your features to numeric and it should work:

```
df['FastText'] = pd.to_numeric(df['FastText'])
df['FastText_Title'] = pd.to_numeric(df['FastText_Title'])
```